# How can I track a ticket's status?

Tags: support, contact-form

I had raised a ticket on Stack Overflow. I received a ticket number to my Email ID.

Help Center → Contact

**Where can I check the status of the ticket that I raised?**

Comment: It's been more than 14 days since I raised the ticket.

Comment: What is your ticket about ? It could determine the time SO will take to handle it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no supported way to view your tickets in the FreshDesk instance SO is using. From [Animuson's answer on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/343083/158100):

> [W]e do use Freshdesk, which has a separate portal with ticket viewing capabilities. We don't explicitly support this, which is why the login options are hidden in the portal, but if you can manage to get yourself [logged in](https://www.stackoverflow.help/support/login) using the same email address you used to contact us, you can view your correspondence for the past year there ...

If you don't manage to login, don't bother asking any further, just wait. Tickets can take [6 to 8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514) before they are handled.